# Problems with Parse json to retrieve the web page response

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json

I have this web page response :

```
{"Status":"OK","RequestID":"xxxxxxxxxx","Results":[{"SubscriberKey":"teste132133","Client":null,"ListID":0,"CreatedDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00.000","Status":"Active","PartnerKey":null,"PartnerProperties":null,"ModifiedDate":null,"ID":0,"ObjectID":null,"CustomerKey":null,"Owner":null,"CorrelationID":null,"ObjectState":null,"IsPlatformObject":false}],"HasMoreRows":false}
```

And I would like to just retrieve the SubscriberKey, like : "SubscriberKey":"teste132133"

So, I'm trying to use the Parse Json, but I believe that I'm doing something wrong that I don't know
follow the code :

```
<script language="javascript" runat="server">

Platform.Load("Core","1");
  
var response = HTP.Get("https://xxxxxxxx.pub.sfmc-content.com/vjpsefyn1jp"); //web page link
var obj = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(response);
Write(obj.Results[0].SubscriberKey)

</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think you're doing something wrong? What happens? What do you expect to happen? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Yes, It's giving 500 - Internal server error., I'm expecting to happen like : SubscriberKey : teste132133, I just want to see the Subscriberkey, not the others attributes

Comment: You'll have to figure out why you're getting the internal server error from the website, assuming it's your website. Othewrwise you'll never get the successful response you're after. Perhaps you should also check for a success response too.

Answer (score 0):

I only know client side JavaScript, maybe this will work for you, it uses fetch to get the reponse, and then extracts the json value. It uses an asynchronous function call so we can use `await` to make the code more readible.

```js
<script type="module">
async function getKey() {
   const response = await fetch("https://xxxxxxxx.pub.sfmc-content.com/vjpsefyn1jp")
   const json = await response.json()
   const Results = json.Results
   const key = Results[0].SubscriberKey
   return key;
}
const key = await getKey();
console.log(`The key is: ${key}`);
</script>
```